# Keep getting error messages in C what do they mean?

Tags: c, cs50

Can someone please explain to me what these error messages mean I keep getting  "error: expected ';' after top level declaration" and  "expected identifier or '('". I am very new to programming and don't understand any and all advice is appreciated. Also is my program coded correctly? Its meant to check if the sides the user inputs result in a triangle. Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
bool check_triangle(float x, float y, float z);
int main(void)

{
     printf("what is the length of the first side of the triangle: ");
     float x = get_float();
     printf("what is the length of the second side of the triangle: ");
     float y = get_float();
      printf("what is the length of the third side of the triangle: ");
     float z = get_float();
    
bool check_triangle(float x, float y, float z);
    if
        {
            (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0)
            return false;
        }
    if  
         {
            ( x+ y <= z || x +  <= y || y + z <= x)
             return false;
         }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Start by fixing your indentation.  That should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'll do that right now!

Comment: Why do you have a dangling `main`? Also `check_triangle` is missing the closing `}`.

Comment: you don't have even the basic syntax remotely right. Your functions are inside main. You have `;` after the function declaration but then you go on and write the function body. Your `if` condition is after the `{`. Stop throwing things at the wall and hope that somehow something will stick. Revisit your courses/books introductory chapters and try and replicate simple examples one at a time. Writing code randomly and then asking what is wrong won't get you anywhere.

Comment: @kaylum thank you for your help. What does it mean to have a dangling main? Sorry if thats a noob question.

Comment: @bolov Thank you for the advice I'm definitely going to be going back to the course after this. Just trying to get a bit more understanding anyway I can.

Comment: @alext1863 I know it might be daunting when starting to learn from 0. That's why you should take 1 thing at a time. Just write a very very simple program with just 1 `if`. That's all. Just 1 `if` in `main`. After you get that right write a very very simple program with just 1 very very simple function - no `if`s no nothing else. Attack 1 thing at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects of syntax you are struggling with as you work to learn C. To begin, C does not allow nested functions. While a missing closing `'}'` for `main()` may explain part of the issue -- it looks like you were attempting to define `check_triangle()` inside of `main()` -- that won't work.

Next, unless the function is so long it is prohibitive to simply place above `main()` without completely messing up your file, forget trying to provide a function prototype above `main()` and the definition below -- you can do that later.

In your test, `x +  <= y` is an incomplete expression. It appears you just left `z` out by accident. You then include a stray `';'` after your attempted *definition* of `check_triangle()` -- a function is `return type function_name (arguments) { /* body */ }` with no `';'` after the closing `')'` defining the arguments.

If you fix those, your function would look like:

```
bool check_triangle (float x, float y, float z) {
    
    if (x <= 0. || y <= 0. || z <= 0.) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if ( x + y <= z || x + z <= y || y + z <= x) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

In CS50, your `get_float()` function expects a string to provide as a prompt. You do not need separate `printf` statements. Instead, you need, e.g.:

```
    float x = get_float("Length of the first side of the triangle: ");
    
    float y = get_float("Length of the second side of the triangle: ");
    
    float z = get_float("Length of the third side of the triangle: ");
```

Lastly, you need to call the function `check_triangle()` to check if what was entered was a triangle. There you just use the function name and argument list. (you need to check the return to know whether you have a triangle or not). So after you obtain `x`, `y`, and `z`, you need to do something like:

```
    if (check_triangle (x, y, z)) {
        puts ("\nyou have a triangle");
    }
    else {
        puts ("\nnot a triangle");
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool check_triangle (float x, float y, float z) {
    
    if (x <= 0. || y <= 0. || z <= 0.) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if ( x + y <= z || x + z <= y || y + z <= x) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

int main (void) {
    
    float x = get_float("Length of the first side of the triangle: ");
    
    float y = get_float("Length of the second side of the triangle: ");
    
    float z = get_float("Length of the third side of the triangle: ");
    
    if (check_triangle (x, y, z)) {
        puts ("\nyou have a triangle");
    }
    else {
        puts ("\nnot a triangle");
    }
}
```

To compile, always compile with *warnings enabled* (for gcc/clang `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and I suggest `-Wshadow`) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. If you call your source file `checktriangle.c`, you could use:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -o checktriangle checktriangle.c -lcs50
```

Then you should be able to test your code. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This really helped clear some things up for me. Thank you so much for your time and the detail you put into this I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the few mistakes I found in the code

1. Closing brace `}` of `main`is missing
2. In function deceleration  `bool check_triangle(float x, float y, float z);` no semi colon is required and opening brace `{` is missing.
3. In `if`, condition should be `if(your condition)` in this format, instead of `if{}`.
4. `x +  <= y` is wrong lvalue, missing `x+something <= y`
5. Follow proper formatting for readability.

See the below code with corrected these.

- Assuming `#include <cs50.h>` & `get_float()` you are taking care

  ```
   #include <cs50.h>

   #include <stdio.h>

   bool check_triangle(float x, float y, float z);

   int main(void)
   {
         float x, y, z;

         printf("what is the length of the first side of the triangle: \n");
         x = get_float();
         printf("what is the length of the second side of the triangle: \n");
         y = get_float();
         printf("what is the length of the third side of the triangle: \n");
         z = get_float();

         if(check_triangle(x,y,z))
         {
               printf("Check triangle is success\n ");
         }
         else
         {
               printf("Check triangle failed\n ");
         }
         return 0;
     }

     bool check_triangle(float x, float y, float z)    
     {     
           if(x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0)
           {
                return false;
           }
           if( x + y <= z || x + z  <= y || y + z <= x)
           {
                return false;
           }
           return true;
       }
  ```